# gRPC fails when building from source

Tags: grpc

I'm doing a project for school and we have to install `gRPC` and `protocol buffer` dependencies for c++. I have been following the build instructions here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md
I am building on Ubuntu 19 and when I run `make` from the root `grpc/` I get the below error.

```
src/cpp/common/channel_filter.cc: In member function ‘grpc_linked_mdelem* grpc::MetadataBatch::AddMetadata(const string&, const string&)’:
src/cpp/common/channel_filter.cc:33:48: error: ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’ clearing an object of non-trivial type ‘grpc_linked_mdelem’ {aka ‘struct grpc_linked_mdelem’}; use assignment or value-initialization instead [-Werror=class-memaccess]
   memset(storage, 0, sizeof(grpc_linked_mdelem));
                                                ^
In file included from ./src/core/lib/transport/transport.h:34,
                 from ./src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack.h:48,
                 from src/cpp/common/channel_filter.cc:21:
./src/core/lib/transport/metadata_batch.h:33:16: note: ‘grpc_linked_mdelem’ {aka ‘struct grpc_linked_mdelem’} declared here
 typedef struct grpc_linked_mdelem {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [Makefile:2926: /home/n0auth/Project3/grpc/objs/opt/src/cpp/common/channel_filter.o] Error 1
```

My `protoc` version

```
libprotoc 3.0.0
```

My `gcc` version

```
gcc (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like downgrading to `gcc-7` and `g++-7` worked for me.
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 70 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-7`

Then I set gcc-7 with highest priority
`sudo update-alternatives --config gcc`

Then I tried to `make install` again and there were no errors.